# Conversion from map containing subclass pointers to map containing superclass pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, stl

So I've got the following simple class hierarchy:

```
class Parent { ... };
class Child : public Parent { ... };
```

I want to do the following:

```
class Class1 {
  Class1(const hash_map<int64, const Parent*>& parent_map) :
    parent_map_(parent_map) { ... }
 private:
  const hash_map<int64, const Parent*>& parent_map_;
};
```

Later:

```
hash_map<int64, const Child*> child_map;
Class1 class_1(child_map);
```

And I'm getting an error saying that no conversion from `hash_map<int64, const Child*>` to `hash_map<int64, const Parent*>` exists.

I've also tried replacing the pointers with `std::unique_ptr`s, and that saw the same compiler error. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is an alternative suggestion:**

You actually have a single `hash_map` instance here.

So you can simply declare this instance using the base-class:

```
hash_map<int64, const Parent*> map;
```

And then you can add either `Parent` or `Child` instances to your `map` at will...

Comment: Sorry, my original post wasn't a good representation of what I was trying to do. I've made an edit.

Comment: OK, after reviewing your updated post, I still think that you can use `Parent` hash-maps all across your program, and exploit polymorphism in order to add `Parent` and `Child` instances at will.

Comment: It's a little more subtle than that: I don't want to convert the child class to the parent class, but rather a *container* of child instances to a *container* of parent instances, and the compiler doesn't like that.

Comment: I honestly do understand what you want, that's why I stated at the top of my answer `Here is an alternative suggestion`. As I said, if your container is defined with the base class, then it can be used with **all** types and subtypes of the same class. If you want to fill it only with sub-type (`Child`) instances - no problem. If you have two separate maps, one for `Child` instances and one for `Parent` instances - no problem, you can still have them both as `Parent` containers. It would ultimately make your code a lot more generic (that's my personal opinion).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new map whose elements are converted from those of the original map, e.g.:

```
hash_map<int64, const Parent*> parent_map(child_map.begin(), child_map.end());
```

You'll have to keep the two in sync manually.

Comment: Sorry, my original post wasn't a good representation of what I was trying to do. I've made an edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly, as a container that stores Child objects is not convertible to a container that stores Parent objects. You need to do the conversion on an item-by-item basis:

```
hash_map<int64, const Child*> child_map;

// stuff.

hash_map<int64, const Parent*> parent_map(child_map.begin(), child_map.end());
Class1 class_1(parent_map);
```

Or, as suggested by Kerrek SB, just store a hash_map of pointers to Parent, instead, and you can store both.